# Emulator without GPU emulation detected

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am trying to execute a sample C2DM Application, but I get an

> "Emulator without GPU emulation detected"`

message in my Logcat.

Answer (score 27):

In Android SDK Tools R15 you can enable GPU emulation.

You need to create a new emulator virtual device and set GPU emulation to true in Hardware properties.

Comment: there is an option to edit the existing emulators without creating new one.

Answer (score 11):

GPU enabling is now is allowed directly through Emulator Creation option.Go to Window --> Android Virtual Device Manager --> new .Now remember to check mark "Use GPU host", then you will have pretty fast working emulator with GPU enable.

Answer (score 0):

Android Virtual Device Manager `->` Edit AVD `->` Show Advanced settings `->`
Emulated Performce: `Automatic`
`Check` Multi-Сore CPU