# The Datepicker is not running?

Tags: android, date, android-emulator, android-edittext, android-datepicker

If i run this, unfortunately the app is closed.
But i tried a lot,i can't get the date in text field.
There is an error in the showdialog,
It returns add the superwarnings.
[image: Layout image]

```
package com.task.reminder;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Add extends Activity 
{

    static final int DATE_ID = 0;
    private  int tMonth;
    private int tYear;
    private int tDay;
    private EditText et2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    private Button datebut=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        getdate();
    }



        private void getdate() 
        {
            datebut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    showDialog(DATE_ID);
                }
            });

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            tYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            tMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            tDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            displaydate();

        }   

        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
        {
                switch(id)
                {
                case DATE_ID:
                        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                                 tYear, tMonth,tDay);
                }
                return null;
        }


        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener=
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
        {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                            int dayOfMonth) 
                    {
                        tYear=year;
                        tMonth=monthOfYear;
                        tDay=dayOfMonth;
                        displaydate();
                    }
        };


        private void displaydate() 
        {


            et2.setText(new StringBuilder().append(tMonth+1).append("-").append(tDay).append("-").append(tYear).append(" "));


        }    


}
```

I need some help, thanks For ur contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following example it works

**CalendarActivity .java**

```
public class CalendarActivity extends Activity
{
 private EditText Calctrl;
 static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
 private String sdate;
 private String[] arrayMonth = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
   "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   Calctrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
   mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
   sdate = currentDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
  Calctrl.setText(sdate);  

  Calctrl.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
  {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
   {
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    return true;
   }
  });
 }

 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
 {
  switch (id)
  {
  case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
   return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,mDay);
  }
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog)
 {
  switch (id)
  {
  case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
   ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
   break;
  }
 } 

 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
 {
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth)
  {
   mYear = year;
   mMonth = monthOfYear;
   mDay = dayOfMonth;
   String sdate = currentDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
   Calctrl.setText(sdate);
  }
 };

 private static String LPad(String schar, String spad, int len)
 {
  String sret = schar;
  for (int i = sret.length(); i < len; i++)
  {
   sret = spad + sret;
  }
  return new String(sret);
 }

 private String currentDate(int year, int month, int day)
 {
  String sdate = arrayMonth[month] + " " + LPad(day + "", "0", 2) + ", "+ year;
  return sdate;
 }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/datepicker"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false"
        android:inputType="none" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Source [here](http://www.androidchennai.blogspot.in/2012/05/simple-calendar-control-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to find View's without setting layout for Activity so more all `findViewById` lines after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);` in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of Activity. Change your code as:

```
public class Add extends Activity 
{

    static final int DATE_ID = 0;
    private  int tMonth;
    private int tYear;
    private int tDay;
    EditText et2 ;
    Button datebut;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
        et2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        datebut=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
          // your code here....
```

Comment: After changing that, getting the same problem,

Comment: In the logcat,    12-04 11:02:05.035: D/gralloc_goldfish(721): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

Comment: @AndRaGhu : this is another issue not programming related see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323371/emulator-without-gpu-emulation-detected

Comment: Very much eager to learn android app developing, so I need a better document or site to understand the android concept each nook and corner...

Comment: @AndRaGhu : great welcome in android imagine world dear. just set http://developer.android.com set homepage in your web browser barbecue everything is available here

Comment: Now trying to develop a task manager app, so how can i save the created tasks in the app.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20565/discussion-between-andraghu-and-imran-khan)

Comment: @AndRaGhu : yesterday i think i have also solved your one issue. but i don't known why you are  not  accepting my answers ?

Answer (score 0):

below is my code which i have done to show date in textview on click of button.
..on click on button datepicker will pop up .you just select the date,it will set that 
date to respective textview.
hope this will help..

```
TextView starttext1;
Button startdatecustom;
DateFormat fmtDateAndTime = DateFormat.getDateInstance();

private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
starttext1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startdateedittext1);

startdatecustom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstdateactcutom);

startdatecustom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {



            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, d, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show(); 

        }
    });

}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    }
};

private void updateLabel() {
    starttext1.setText(fmtDateAndTime.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        // set date picker as current date
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

    }
};
```