# my eclipse ide has some problems. whenever i run any android application i get errors in logcat: error opening trace file-No such file or directory

Tags: android, eclipse

This is the stack trace:

```
    07-15 08:46:48.599: E/Trace(2905): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    07-15 08:46:49.149: D/gralloc_goldfish(2905): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

//this happens when i perform any event in my app and my app force close

```
      07-15 08:49:19.109: D/AndroidRuntime(2905): Shutting down VM
        07-15 08:49:19.109: W/dalvikvm(2905): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method startNew(View) in the activity class com.example.mainn.MainAct for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: startNew [class android.view.View]
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3579)
        07-15 08:49:19.139: E/AndroidRuntime(2905):     ... 11 more
        07-15 08:49:20.510: I/Process(2905): Sending signal. PID: 2905 SIG: 9
        07-15 08:57:14.279: E/Trace(3072): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
        07-15 08:57:14.849: D/gralloc_goldfish(3072): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
        07-15 08:57:37.219: D/AndroidRuntime(3072): Shutting down VM
        07-15 08:57:37.219: W/dalvikvm(3072): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method startNew(View) in the activity class com.example.mainn.MainAct for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: startNew [class android.view.View]
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3579)
        07-15 08:57:37.259: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):
```

my eclipse ide has some problems. whenever i run any android application i get errors in logcat: error opening trace file-No such file or directory like the above result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323371/emulator-without-gpu-emulation-detected

Comment: i tried enabling gpu emulation but it is showing me error while launching avd.  error: Starting emulator for AVD 'device1'
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.