# Why Android app uses over 90 % CPU in Android emulator, but only 30 % on phone?

Tags: android, memory-management, android-studio, emulation, cpu-usage

I have developed a chess game using Android Studio 1.4.1 that uses tens of threads to do AI move calculation. When run on Android Nexus 5 API 23 x86 emulator, the CPU usage is over 90 % during the AI move calculations, around 40 % being kernel, and the memory usage looks like hedgehog's back. When run on Samsung Galaxy S III 4G (Android 4.4.4), the CPU usage stays under 30 % and memory usage looks very smooth, with lots of garbage collection messages in Android Studio.

The result is that my AI takes massively longer time to think its moves, because of the low CPU utilization. Is there some CPU usage per app restriction on Android phones?

Answer (score 2):

There is no GPU in the emulator, thats why the CPU Usage is so hight.

Update:

you can enable the GPU: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23607021/2494799 ..

> Caution: As of SDK Tools Revision 17, the graphics acceleration feature for the emulator is experimental; be alert for incompatibilities and errors when using this feature.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#acceleration

`Is there some CPU usage per app restriction on Android phones?` yes there is, it's the kernel in your phone who specify the amount of resources (ram cpu..) allocated to each app (process) depending on what currently running, heat... what you should do is to focus on your app code to improve performance based on your devices not the emulator

Comment: Could it be that over 70 % is consistently used for commanding the GPU? My app refreshes the screen 2 times per second and when the screen is touched. In my overridden onDraw method for my SurfaceView I do nothing.

Comment: i think you can't refer to that because here http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration they are saying that "the graphics acceleration feature for the emulator is experimental; be alert for incompatibilities and errors when using this feature."

Comment: have you tried to activate The GPU in the emulator? if no http://stackoverflow.com/a/23607021/2494799

Comment: If you mean unticking the "Use Host GPU", I tried that, but the emulated Android has black screen only. Perhaps you have misunderstood my question. The CPU usage is NOT my Windows PC, but what Android Studio shows for the emulator/phone.

Comment: i think i understand now you question, `Is there some CPU usage per app restriction on Android phones?` yes there is, it's the kernel in your phone who specify the amount of resources (ram cpu..) allocated to each app (process) depending on what currently running, heat... what you should do is to focus on your app code to improve performance based on your devices not the emulator.

Comment: Can I make my app take 90 % of CPU time? I found the touch screen input very laggy, so maybe extracting some code to threads will help a little.

Comment: definitely that the way how you can improve performance, i don't know about your code but asynctask, intentservice... also helps. good luck

Answer (score 0):

The Android Emulator is very slow.

The main reason: It is emulating the ARM CPU & GPU, which runs x86 code instead of the ARM code that runs on the actual hardware.

You can use Genymotion. This emulator much faster.

Or

If you install the HAXM in android SDK manager then the emulator works better.

Comment: The emulator is a lot faster than my phone.