# Game wont fully load on Android (Xamarin/CocosSharp)

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, cocossharp

Let me start by saying that i'm new to Xamarin/Cocossharp and game development in general.
I did a very basic game/application starting from the Cocossharp template for Shared application in VS2015. Now my app works well on WP (Emulator & Device) but wont start up on android.
After the emulator laoded this is what i get:

[android 4.4 emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zS76.jpg)

No Exception has been generated. I only get those errors in the output window, but they don't actually crash the application:

[debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yG0L.jpg)

it looks like the Android version of the app doesn't go further than the class MainActivity.cs, which is generated by the template and should not be necessarily modified. Btw I have the same problem while trying to  execute the examples from Xamarin.com

strugling with this issue since two days, help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator without GPU emulation detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323371/emulator-without-gpu-emulation-detected)

Comment: feeling so stupid right now. I didn't realize that was a significant error. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, happens to all of us.. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was already answered.

It was only necessary to set GPU emulation to true in Hardware properties of the virtual device.